# How can i know who is using a port?

Tags: port

When I browse "localhost:8080" it ask me to authenticate, but I do not know which program is using that port.

My question is: how can I know which program is using that port?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the following two methods, depending on your OS :)

## Windows

- Open the command prompt - start » run » cmd or start » All Programs »
  Accessories » Command Prompt.
- Type `netstat -aon | findstr '[8080]'`
- If the port is being used by any application, then that application’s
  detail will be shown. The number, which is shown at the last column
  of the list, is the PID  (process ID) of that application. Make note
  of this.
- Type `tasklist | findstr '[PID]'`. Replace the [PID] with the number
  from the above step and hit enter.
- You will then be shown the application name that is using your port
  number

---

## Linux (Debian/Ubuntu)

- open the terminal and enter `sudo apt install net-tools`
- open the terminal and enter `netstat -ltnp | grep -w ':8080'`
- You should then see the application using said port on the far right
  of the terminal `[PID]/SomeApplicationName`

Comment: You are right, i should have specified the OS, I am currently running on windows. I have made what you have said but I have some problem, in fact if I run the comand "netstat -a" for instance it shows me that the local address 0.0.0.0:8080 is in use but if i run the comand you have said it does not show me the expected answer. It actually does not show me anything!

Comment: Ok, I got it. I have to type `netstat -aon | findstr 8080` and then `tasklist | findstr PID`.

Answer (score -2):

https://www.tecmint.com/10-lsof-command-examples-in-linux/

`lsof`: is the command you need